# media query css for small screens

Tags: css, media-queries

Question: How does one use css @media to target all screens below 1024x600?

I need to tell all small monitor screens to use overflow-x:scroll.

Context: I had to use the following CSS rule on both the HTML and BODY tags:

overflow-x:hidden !important;

(Otherwise certain animations cause ugly horizontal scrollbars to appear on the page.)

But now, when viewing my site using smaller screens, it would be nice if the user could scroll the page horizontally.

I'll keep looking for a css snippet that does this, but I'm posting this because the site just went live and it's about to get hit with tons of traffic, so I need something quick.

Answer (score 2):

I found answers pretty quickly (http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml), but I still need to figure out how to test this online.

```
/* CSS that's applied when the viewing area's width is 800px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  html{
  overflow-x:auto !important;
  }
  body{
  overflow-x:auto !important;
  }
}
```

Where does one go to test if this actually works, because testsize.com doesn't show the scrollbars (and I'm not sure if it's their limitation or my own).

Comment: You just have to resize your browser window to test media-queries. You can also try some bookmarklet : http://codebomber.com/jquery/resizer/

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+M is also a neat trick for testing in Firefox (not sure from which version).